# getting ASCII tilemaps from a text file?

Tags: c++, ascii

I'm trying to write a map reader for Nitemare 3D, each map block is 2 bytes(1 for the tile and 1 for the item on the tile) each map is 64*64 blocks, the map file file itself contains several maps, I've loaded the map and dumped it into a textfile but it comes out mangled

Edit: for those seeking the answer, I forgot to add std::ios::binary when outputting lol

code:

```
std::ifstream is;

is.open("MAP.1", std::ios::binary);

char* mapbuff = new char[8192];
is.seekg(514);
is.read(mapbuff, 8192);

std::ofstream myfile("map1.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 64 * 64*2; i++) {
        myfile << mapbuff[i];
    }
    
    myfile.close();
}
```

[mapfile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E1hCQaqfR5at0pkKgbKuyt7RhMua9IYC/view)

what it's supposed to look like:
[image: the mapfile in a hex editor]

what it looks like after I dump it:
[image]

Comment: You need to reverse engineer the file format in order to know where the map starts. Once you have that it is just a matter of jumping to the right offset, reading bytes and storing them in an internal datastructure. The file size is not exactly a multiple of 64x64x2, so there is probably either some kind of header, or not all maps are exactly 64x64x2 bytes large.

Comment: Maps seem to start at offset 514; every map seems to be 8192 (=64*64*2) bytes large. Up to you to determine what is in those first 514 bytes.

Comment: As for the actual reading, just use `fread` or `std::ifstream::read` to dump it in a `char[8192]`. You can then either build accessors on that array or transfer it into an actual two-dimensional array. Both are fine.

Comment: @Botje I read the map into a array using ifstream, most of it is fine but the rest is mangled garbage, I'm editing my question to showcase this

Comment: You did not include your code, but the screenshot (don't do that, please) shows that you opened the output file in text mode instead of binary mode, which translates all 0x0A bytes into 0x0D 0x0A bytes. Add `std::ios::binary` to your `ofstream` constructor or `open` call. (You probably want to do this for the reading part too)

Comment: @Botje that doesn't change anything, also I added my code to the question

Comment: You are not writing the file in binary mode.

Comment: @BBQGiraffe Sorry, I meant putting the *output* stream in binary mode. I made my edit right after you saw it, I guess.

Comment: @Botje yeah that fixes everything lol

Comment: As a final remark, consider using `std::ofstream::write` instead of putting 8192 bytes individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Windows and you are not writing the file in binary mode. Each time you write a newline - `\n` - 0x0A - it gets converted to a CR + newline - `\r\n` - 0x0D then 0x0A. This adds an extra byte which makes the files not match up.

To fix this, use `std::ios::binary` in the output stream as well.